# Laravel - Disabled cookies without login

Tags: laravel, authentication, cookies, frameworks

If a user opens a website, he's getting instantly redirected to a login page. Unfortunately, Laravel stores two cookies (example_domain_session and XSRF-TOKEN). Is there any way how to disable this feature and allow cookies only after being logged in?

Unfortunately, I didn't found any helpful solution yet on the internet or their documentation. I'm using the latest version of the framework.

Thank you.

Comment: can I ask why you want to do that? do you not need the session for any pages that would get the user redirected to the login page? or is this only related to the homepage?

Comment: @lagbox Well, it's a private domain and if you do not save any cookies, you don't need a note's regarding to privacy  or the GDPR of europe. I also do not want to use htaccess protection.

Comment: so any page they access at all that redirects them to login, unless they login there shouldn't be a cookie? or just the homepage/landing page/root?

Comment: Example: User opens "example.com" -> getting instantly redirected to login if he isn't logged in yet. It's not public. Do you understand?

Comment: Did you add auth middleware to all pages? Because being redirected is **not** default behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I do. "'auth' => Authenticate::class," is located in $routeMiddleware

Comment: do you actually need the XSRF-TOKEN in your application?

Comment: Well, isn't it required for use in forms?

Comment: for regular forms you are adding the csrf token yourself as a hidden input ... regardless if you end up not having the session cookie, then you won't be able to verify the csrf token, which means your login form won't be able to use a csrf token

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify your App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken by adding which routes will not use this token.

I think it will help.

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with not having a CSRF token for the login action and you don't need the X-XSRF-TOKEN cookie in your application then I suppose you could try what you are asking for.

Since you are applying the `auth` middleware to all these routes (which relies on the session) you would probably have to extend the `StartSession` middleware and modify it to not add the cookie to the response if someone isn't authenticated. Or you could create a separate middleware that sets the session config driver to `null` if there isn't an authenticated user after the response comes back through (after `$next($request)` is called); which would cause the `StartSession` middleware to think the session isn't persistent and it wouldn't add the cookie to the response.

For the XSRF-Token cookie you can tell your `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware to not add the cookie to the response. You would then need to exclude the `login` action route from the CSRF verification via your `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware:

```
protected $addHttpCookie = false;

protected $excepts = [
    'login',
];
```

A bunch of IFs here and a bad idea not having the CSRF token for the login action.